# Count Number of Swaps in Merge Sort (Java)

Tags: java, mergesort

Im trying to find the number of times the elements in an array are swapped to sort the array. The program uses recursion and merge sort. After trying many times by putting a counter in what i believe where the sort happens i get what looks like to be randomly generated numbers as the number of swaps.

Here is the code. I just want a number that shows the correct amount of swaps rather than the random numbers.

```
    /**
 * 
 * @author Frank Stalteri
 *
 */
public class mergeExample {
    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] list = {2, 3, 2, 5, 6, 1, -2, 3, 14, 12};
        /**
         * performs merge sort
         */
        mergeSort(list);
        /**
         * prints array to screen
         */
        printArray(list);
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param list
     */
    public static void mergeSort(int [] list) {
        if (list.length > 1) {
            /**
             * merge first half of array
             */
            int [] firstHalf = new int[list.length / 2];
            System.arraycopy(list, 0, firstHalf, 0, list.length / 2);
            mergeSort(firstHalf);
            /**
             * merge second part of array
             */
            int secondHalfLength = list.length - list.length / 2;
            int [] secondHalf = new int[secondHalfLength];
            System.arraycopy(list, list.length / 2, secondHalf, 0, secondHalfLength);
            mergeSort(secondHalf);
            /**
             * put the sorted parts together
             */
            merge(firstHalf, secondHalf, list);
        }
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param list1
     * @param list2
     * @param temp
     * @return 
     */
    public static void merge(int [] list1, int [] list2, int [] temp) {
        int current1 = 0;   //current index in list1
        int current2 = 0;   //current index in list2
        int current3 = 0;   //current index in temp

        while (current1 < list1.length && current2 < list2.length) {
            if (list1[current1] < list2[current2]) {
                temp[current3++] = list1[current1++];
            }
            else {
                temp[current3++] = list2[current2++];
            }
        }
        while (current1 < list1.length) {           
            temp[current3++] = list1[current1++];

        }
        while (current2 < list2.length) {
            temp[current3++] = list2[current2++];
        }
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param list
     */
    public static void printArray(int [] list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output

```
1
1
1
2
0
0
1
2
5
-2 1 2 2 3 3 5 6 12 14
```

Comment: You're only printing `list` so what's printing your "random" numbers?

Comment: you don't count anything in your code. update it

Comment: Well whats printing the numbers is the sysout code that i would put in the merge function. I just realized that its not there because i forgot i removed it before coming here to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to add something like a count variable outside your merge function, for example as a `static int` in your class:

```java
public class MergeExample {
    static int mergeCount = 0;
    // ...
}
```

and whenever you do a swap in your code in your `mergeSort` function you'd have to increment `MergeExample.mergeCount` by 1. In the end, you will have the number of swaps performed in that variable.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It appears it worked. The output instead went as "1, 2, 3... 19".

Comment: @zOrigin_ And that's how it's supposed to be, right? Glad I could help.